# PHP DOM: parsing a HTML list into an array?

Tags: php, dom, php-5.3, html-parsing

I have the below HTML string, and I would like to turn it into an array.

```
$string = '
<a href="#" class="something">1</a>
<a href="#" class="something">2</a>
<a href="#" class="something">3</a>
<a href="#" class="something">4</a>
';
```

Here's my current code with `DOMDocument`:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($string);
foreach( $dom->getElementsByTagName('a') as $node)
{
    $array[] = $node->nodeValue; 
}

print_r($array);
```

However, this gives the below output:

```
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 2 [3] => 4)
```

But I am looking for this result:

```
Array ( 
[0] => <a href="#" class="something">1</a>
[1] => <a href="#" class="something">2</a> 
[2] => <a href="#" class="something">3</a>
[3] => <a href="#" class="something">4</a>
)
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Pass the node to [`DOMDocument::saveHTML`](https://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savehtml.php) to get its HTML representation:

```
$string = '
<a href="#" class="something">1</a>
<a href="#" class="something">2</a>
<a href="#" class="something">3</a>
<a href="#" class="something">4</a>
';

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($string);
foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('a') as $node)
{
    $array[] = $dom->saveHTML($node);
}

print_r($array);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => <a href="#" class="something">1</a>
    [1] => <a href="#" class="something">2</a>
    [2] => <a href="#" class="something">3</a>
    [3] => <a href="#" class="something">4</a>
)
```

Only works with PHP 5.3.6 and higher, by the way.

Comment: nice, didn't know about the new node param.