# Parse html to PHP array

Tags: php, html, regex, dom, browser

I have this HTML Template:

```
<div>
  <p class="ex-fr">Tex1 - Edit</p>

  Out Text 1 Edit

  <p>Tex2 - Edit</p>

  Out Text 1 Edit

  <br>

  Out Text 3 Edit

</div>
```

I would like to create a page for editing the text of this Template and  the Tags attribute.

For doing this, i need to parse this html into a php array and load the page.

This is an hypothetical array that I could get from the html written above:

```
$parsedHtml = array(
        'thisIs'=>'tag',
        'tag' => 'div',
        'attr' => '',
        'children'=> array(
            0 => array(
                'thisIs'=>'tag',
                'tag' => 'p',
                'attr' => 'class="ex-fr"',
                'children'=> array(
                    'thisIs'=>'text',
                    'tag' => '',
                    'attr' => '',
                    'children'=> 'Tex1 - Edit'
                )
            ),
            1 => array(
                'thisIs'=>'text',
                'tag' => '',
                'attr' => '',
                'children'=> 'Out Text 1 Edit'
            ),
            2 => array(
                'thisIs'=>'tag',
                'tag' => 'p',
                'attr' => '',
                'children'=> array(
                    'thisIs'=>'text',
                    'tag' => '',
                    'attr' => '',
                    'children'=> 'Tex2 - Edit'
                )
            ),
            3 => array(
                'thisIs'=>'text',
                'tag' => '',
                'attr' => '',
                'children'=> 'Out Text 2 Edit'
            ),
            4 => array(
                'thisIs'=>'sTag',
                'tag' => 'br',
                'attr' => '',
                'children'=> ''
            ),
            5 => array(
                'thisIs'=>'text',
                'tag' => '',
                'attr' => '',
                'children'=> 'Out Text 3 Edit'
            )

        )

    );
```

At the moment I have tried to use this Class:
https://code.google.com/p/php-html2array/downloads/detail?name=class.htmlParser.php
The problem is that the class is returning only the tag, while the text without tags should be ignored like "Out Text 1 Edit" OR "Out Text 2 Edit"

So the given array is

```
(
[-{}-2-0-{}-] => Array
    (
        [id] => -{}-2-0-{}-
        [father] => 
        [tag] => div
        [innerHTML] =>  <p class='ex-fr'>Tex1 - Edit</p> Out Text 1 Edit <p>Tex2 - Edit</p> Out Text 1 Edit <br> Out Text 3 Edit 
        [htmlText] => <div > <p class='ex-fr'>Tex1 - Edit</p> Out Text 1 Edit <p>Tex2 - Edit</p> Out Text 1 Edit <br> Out Text 3 Edit </div>
        [stratr] => 
        [childNodes] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => -{}-1-0-{}-
                        [father] => -{}-2-0-{}-
                        [tag] => p
                        [innerHTML] => Tex1 - Edit
                        [htmlText] => <p class='ex-fr'>Tex1 - Edit</p>
                        [stratr] =>  class='ex-fr'
                        [childNodes] => Array
                            (
                            )

                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => -{}-1-1-{}-
                        [father] => -{}-2-0-{}-
                        [tag] => p
                        [innerHTML] => Tex2 - Edit
                        [htmlText] => <p>Tex2 - Edit</p>
                        [stratr] => 
                        [childNodes] => Array
                            (
                            )

                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => -{}-0-0-{}-
                        [father] => -{}-2-0-{}-
                        [tag] => br
                        [innerHTML] => <br>
                        [htmlText] => <br>
                        [stratr] => 
                        [childNodes] => Array
                            (
                            )

                    )

            )

    )

)
```

Any idea to parse the html into an array?
(I have searched how the browsers parse the html code and show it in the console, like chrome or firebug, and they permit the edit)

I know that parse html with a regex is hard or impossible, is there another solution?

Thank you all in advance, sorry for my poor english

Best regards Andrea.

Comment: We need [bobince](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2454376)...

Comment: Have you tried [`http://php.net/simplexml`](simplexml)? It won't give you what you desire, but it is a starting point

Comment: Take a look at PHP's [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)

Comment: i hadn't used "simplexml" but i want see if it's possible for do that.
i need a function like this in jquery: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseHTML/

Comment: @mishik my coworkers are wondering why I'm laughing so hard right now... But yeah you can't parse html with with regex

Comment: @ChrisFrank i don't think I had asked how can i parse html with a regex, but if there is another solution...

Comment: @AndreaCatania http://stackoverflow.com/a/10366491/1547278

Comment: @ChrisFrank it's good idea but my template is dynamic and i don't know the specific tag name. if there is a function for navigate between tag without the name, would be perfect

Comment: @AndreaCatania If you have a set of tags which will be dynamically created you could use 'or' in the foreach call. Or you could use http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm

Answer (score 0):

If you familiar with `jQuery`, you can use [phpQuery](https://code.google.com/p/phpquery/) - it's basically the php port. Easy, pretty fast, and well documented.

Comment: @ChrisFrank I tryed with a jquery, this is the code
     
     var str = '<div id="test"><p class="ex-fr">Tex1 - Edit</p>Out Text 1 Edit<p>Tex2 - Edit</p>Out Text 1 Edit<br>Out Text 3 Edit</div>'; 

     $(str).children().each( function( index, value ){

           alert( index+' - '+$(value).contents() );

     });


but it return only the <p> and <br> tag without free text like "Out Text 1 Edit" or "Out Text 1 Edit"

Comment: Because it's wrong code. If you want to get tag name and it's content, you can use something like this $('div#test').each(fucntion(){ alert($(this).attr('tagName') + ' - ' + $(this).html()); });

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your advices I've made the function you can see below.

It won't give to me what I desire, but it is a good starting point.
When I will have the final solution i will post it for you guys Thanks agine for your help.

```
function parseHtml( $parent ){

    foreach( pq( $parent )->contents() as $children ){
        echo '<br>';
        $a = isset( $children->tagName );
        if( $a ){
            echo htmlentities( '<' . $children->tagName . '>' );

        }else{
            echo '<br>';
            echo '"' . htmlentities( $children->textContent ) . '"';
            echo '<br>';
        }


        parseHtml( $children );

        if( $a ){
            echo htmlentities( '</' . $children->tagName . '>' );

        }

     }

}
```