# For each something do something

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have div on index page and it is editable.
Below div I have button for post.
On click on button I send div content to another page called `file.php`
Inside this file I have

```
$text = $_POST['text'];
```

Now I need somehow to check how many opening and closing spans I have inside `$text`

Example:

```
$text = "<span id='first'>first</span> some text <span id='second'>second</span> more text <span id='third'>third</span>";
```

Now foreach opened and closed span foreach span do something else...
How can I check how many span I have in string and do foreach of them something else...

UPDATE:
I tried this:

```
$html = str_get_html($text);
foreach($html->find('a') as $element){ 
       echo $element->href . '<br>';
}
```

And I get fatal error for undefined function in str_get_html

Comment: This might help [How to get span tag content using preg_match function](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18858627/5484276)

Comment: You should *never* parse HTML with regex. Use [a PHP DOM parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) instead.

Comment: @JayBlanchard I tried this: $html = str_get_html($text);
foreach($html->find('a') as $element){ 
       echo $element->href . '<br>';
} But I get fatal error call to undefined function in str_get_html

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$text = "<span id='first'>first</span> some text <span id='second'>second</span> more text <span id='third'>third</span>";

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($text);
foreach( $dom->getElementsByTagName('span') as $node)
{
    echo $node->nodeValue . "<br/>"; 
}
```

Have a look at it here: [PHP DOM: parsing a HTML list into an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10366458/php-dom-parsing-a-html-list-into-an-array)

Comment: I fund solution didn't include phrase file well