# PHP - Scraping a DIV Element from a Web Page using preg_match

Tags: php, html, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

I am trying to use preg_match currently just to retrieve 1 value (before I move onto retrieving multiple values), however, I am having no luck. When I perform a print_r()  there is nothing stored in my array.

Here is my code what i am trying so far:

```
<?php
$content = '<div class="text-right font-90 text-default text-light last-updated vertical-offset-20">
    Reported ETA Received:
    <time datetime="2017-02-02 18:12">2017-02-02 18:12</time>
    UTC
</div>';
preg_match('|Reported ETA Received: <time datetime=".+">(.*)</time>(.*)\(<span title=".+">(.*)<time datetime=".+">(.*)</time></span>\)|', $content, $reported_eta_received);

if ($reported_eta_received) {
    $arr_parsed['reported_eta_received'] = $reported_eta_received[1];
}
?>
```

Required Output:

```
2017-02-02 18:12
```

My above-mentioned code is not working. Any help on this regards would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Checkout domdocument http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10366458/php-dom-parsing-a-html-list-into-an-array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may not match because there is a new line between Reported ETA Received: and the `<time>` tag. And you've just put in there a space (use [\n\r\s\t]+ instead " ").

Also, why don't you simply use:

`preg_match('|<time datetime=".*?">(.*?)</time>|', $content, $reported_eta_received);`

You can also use:`?P<name>` for a easier pointing (associative vs numeric: numeric can change if you put more capture groups).

`preg_match('|<time datetime=".*?">(?P<name>.*?)</time>|', $content, $match);
print_r($match); // $match['name'] should be there if matched.`